# Crystal report report width not complete at run time

Tags: vb.net

When viewing the report at run-time the report comes not in completed width but when I view it at design time it is complete:

[image]

Is there is some way I can fix this?
My program was working correctly previously.

Comment: Are you sure this isn’t printer driver settings?  Almost looks like the paper size has changed from A4 to letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default printer in the runtime environment has a different default page size or different minimum allowed page margins.
If you actually need to print, **set the printer in design time to be compatible (or same) as tuntime's printer**.

If you need to just preview, you can go to File, Page Setup... and turn on the option to '***Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Page Size***'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank a lot
there was an update for microsoft solved this problem

**May 23, 2023-KB5026958 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 for Windows 10 Version 22H2**